# How to get a page from a userspace process for a given task in Linux?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, virtual-memory

What exactly does the virt_to_page function return, does it return the page given an address in the kernel space or does it return a page given an address in user space? As far as I can tell it seems that it takes a kernel address and returns the page for that. If so what can I use to get a page from a user space process given the task or mm_struct and then virtual address?

Comment: I guess this question heading is a bit misleading. virt_to_page is a macro in the linux kernel code which yields the address of the page descriptor associated with kernel address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virt_to_page()` does indeed work only for direct-mapped kernel addresses.  To find a page for a userspace mapping, you need to use `get_user_pages()` (and do a `put_page` when you're done to release the reference on the page).

Comment: so if i do a get_user_pages() (to get the 1 page) once I'm done with it i have to do put_page(page) to release it correct? just want to make sure

Comment: Yes, get_user_pages() takes a reference on each page it returns, and you need to do a matching put_page() on each page to drop that reference again.

Comment: don't forget about the down_read and up_rea on the mmap semaphore in the mm_struct :P